# How the JMeter actually works? Does it add records to the application in real time?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, manual-testing, automation-testing

Can we add data in application(registration form/candidates details etc) using JMeter?
I create script
-HTTP Request where I used ${__UUID()} function to create random UID
-Create HTTP Req with parameters
-Add listener to view result

Script execurted successfully but when i check in application the data not added /displyed

I create script
-HTTP Request where I used ${__UUID()} function to create random UID
-Create HTTP Req with parameters
-Add listener to view result

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level, given you [properly configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) it will send the same HTTP request(s) as the real browser does hence the "record" (whatever it means) will be created.

You can add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your test plan, this way you will be able to see the request and response details and from the response you should be able to figure out what's wrong with your request.